# How to disable javascript unload event in webbrowser control c#?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am using a webbrowser control to navigate to a site that has a JavaScript unload event. When I attempt to navigate elsewhere, a popup appears prompting me if I want to "Stay On Page" or "Leave Page". If I keep attempting to navigate away, a COMException is thrown.
How can I prevent popups like these from occurring in my webbrowser?

**Edit:**
How can I disable Javascript when I am ready to navigate to another webpage?

Comment: How about disabling JavaScript?

Comment: IIRC there should also be an interface to implement so you get notified when a message box is shown.

Comment: Or, how about modifying the DOM after the page is loaded and remove the unload handler?

Comment: @UweKeim so would I just append a script tag with the contents "window.unload=function(){}" into the head tag of all the websites I visit? Will this forsure override the already present unload event?

Comment: @PhilipHardy, it's actually about `onbeforeunload` event, not `unload` event. You might be able to block it with code like `window.onbeforeunload=function(){}`, unless the page uses `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` to handle this event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (Delphi code):

```
var
  WrkIHTMLWindow2: IHTMLWindow2;
  WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp: IHTMLWindow2Disp;
begin
  WrkIHTMLWindow2 := IHTMLDocument2Disp(WrkIWebBrowser2.Document).parentWindow;
  if WrkIHTMLWindow2.QueryInterface(IHTMLWindow2Disp, WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp) = S_OK then
    if not VarIsNull(WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp.onbeforeunload) then
      WrkIHTMLWindow2Disp.onbeforeunload := NULL;
```